# Calculating isotropic basis of a bilinear form.

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, bilinear-form

Let $\phi:V\times V \longrightarrow R$ be a symmetric, bilinear form with signature. A not null vector $v\in V$ is isotropic if $\phi(v,v)=0$.

Suppose that the matrix of $\phi$ in one basis $B=(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)$ is:

$M =
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & -4 & 6 & 0 \\
2 & 6 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$

I am asked to calculate a orthogonal basis to $\phi$ and calculate a isotropic basis to $\phi$.

I have already calculated an orthogonal basis: $(0,0,0,1),(0,1,0,0),(0,\frac{6}{4},1,2),(1,\frac{-3}{4},\frac{-5}{16},\frac{-26}{16})$
However I don't know how to calculate the isotropic basis, when do this basis exists, and how can I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $\varphi(e,f)=0$, $\ \varphi(e,e)=1\ $ and $\ \varphi(f,f)=-1\ $ then $\varphi(e+f,\,e+f)=\varphi(e-f,\,e-f)=0$